# Subquery or similar in logstash/kibana?

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I apologize in advance for my ignorance if this is a stupid question.

I am running into an issue with an application that is, apparently, receiving messages asynchronously and losing responses sporadically. Essentially, I log when a client posts a message to the service and another when it responds. These log entries include a unique correlation id that I can use to cross-reference the requests and responses. We ship the logs to logstash and I have been able to find a few that were caught by clients that have a received log entry and no reply. I'm not at all sure how this could happen.

However, what I need to do first is determine the scope of this issue by comparing the correlation ids. Before moving to logstash we used splunk and I was able to use their join functionality to find such correlations. Is this functionality available via logstash? Or is there an API call I can make to dump individual query results to and run my own logic?

**Previously omitted**
This is a full ELK stack

TIA

Comment: possible duplicate of [With Logstash, how do you combine lines based on matching same timestamp on every line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668070/with-logstash-how-do-you-combine-lines-based-on-matching-same-timestamp-on-ever)

Comment: I was hoping for something without having to write an extension. However, I appreciate the response. I'll give it a shot. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ear today logger messages can be losts with threads. the issue is to make the logger non serializable with annotation @transient
In scala this is the code

```
RegisterLogicalType.register

@transient protected lazy val logger: Logger =
  Logger(LoggerFactory getLogger getClass.getName)
```