# Parse JSON log and for multiline java Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, multiline, logstash-configuration

I have a below JSON log file

```html
{"log":"2017-04-11 05:13:14.623  INFO 1 --- [io-8888-exec-30] .PersistenceArtifactGeneratorServiceImpl : Started generating service artifacts...\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2017-04-11T05:13:14.719142624Z"}
{"log":"java.lang.NullPointerException\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-04-11T05:13:14.72874145Z"}
{"log":"\u0009at com.dharbor.set.fusion.modelservice.service.impl.PersistenceArtifactGeneratorServiceImpl.extractEntityNames(PersistenceArtifactGeneratorServiceImpl.java:145)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2017-04-11T05:13:14.728919982Z"}
```

In that i have 3 lines of log and I am trying to parse this json with

```html
input {
  file {
    type => "json"
    codec => multiline
    {
      pattern => '^\{'
      negate => true
      what => previous                
    }
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    path => ["/host/var/log/jsonlog.log"]
    exclude => "*.gz"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate
  {
    replace => [ "message", "%{message}}" ]
    gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
  }
  if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/ 
  {
    json
    {
      source => message
      remove_field => [ "message" ]
    }
  }
}

output
{   
  elasticsearch {
    codec => json
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

and I want the last 2 log entries to be merged in one index and first one as one entry. I have tried out the above logstasgh.conf but it didn't work.
Seeking for help regarding that and sorry if I am wrong in posting the code as snippet since I am newbie.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? Do you get errors or is your result different from your expectations?

Comment: I am not able to get those lines to merge even by that logstash,conf. I found same issue ([http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668070/with-logstash-how-do-you-combine-lines-based-on-matching-same-timestamp-on-ever] ) but it looks very old.